# How to find the time between two datetimes on symfony 2

Tags: symfony

**This is the code in the controller**

```
            $time = date('H:i:s');

            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainHomeBundle:Tec');

            $count = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')
                ->select('COUNT(t)')
                ->leftJoin('MainHomeBundle:Clients', 'c', 'WITH', 't.townId = c.townId')
                ->where('t.onservice = 0')
                ->andWhere('t.status = 1')
                ->andWhere('t.datestart < ' . $tiempo)
                ->andWhere('t.dateend > ' . $tiempo)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

*t.datestart and t.dateend are datetime fields*

**I find the number of records that match**

2016-01-01 **08:00:00** **>** $time **<** 2015-12-31 **20:00:00**

*Only comparing the times*

***if not a good idea to use > and < or there is some method to make between***

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have them strictly greater and less than, then you are doing it right already. There exists a between operation as well, but that includes the equaling values also in the checks, i.e. using that your check example becomes:

```
2016-01-01 08:00:00 >= $time <= 2015-12-31 20:00:00
```

Additionally the between operation is generally just a syntactic sugar, i.e. it results in same query with greater than and less than (at least on mysql), so performance wise it also doesn't matter which one you use.

Just for reference, you can use the between operation like this:

```
->andWhere($tiempo . ' BETWEEN t.datestart AND t.dateend')
```

And for record, it is a good habit not to catenate parameter values directly into the querybuilder, but rather place them with the setParameter() function (you are probably just using the time that you construct yourself in this case, but still it's a good practice to use the setParameter method always)